# How do I use the typesVersions field in package.json to ship stricter types for newer typescript versions?

Tags: typescript, npm, types, build

According to [the TypeScript 3.1 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#version-selection-with-typesversions), typescript provides a way to ship stricter types in npm packages by setting the `typesVersions` field in `package.json` like so:

```
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "typesVersions": {
    ">=3.1": { "*": ["ts3.1/*"] }
  }
}
```

However, the docs do not indicate how the specified `ts3.1/index.d.ts` file is created. Do I have to manually write an `index.d.ts` file at this location? Is there a way with typescript or a related build tool to conditionally generate stricter types?

Comment: Just found out about a brand new tool for this in progress, and updated my answer. Please take a look again.

Answer (score 8):

**2023, TypeScript 4.9 and beyond**

[`exports` is prioritized over `typesVersions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#exports-is-prioritized-over-typesversions)

Previously, TypeScript incorrectly prioritized the `typesVersions` field over the `exports` field when resolving through a `package.json` under `--moduleResolution node16`. If this change impacts your library, you may need to add `types@` version selectors in your `package.json`’s `exports` field. The proper way to do this is using `exports` field now -

```json
{
      "type": "module",
      "main": "./dist/main.js"
      "typesVersions": {
          "<4.8": { ".": ["4.8-types/main.d.ts"] },
          "*": { ".": ["modern-types/main.d.ts"] }
      },
      "exports": {
          ".": {
              "types@<4.8": "4.8-types/main.d.ts",  ✅
              "types": "modern-types/main.d.ts",    ✅
              "import": "./dist/main.js"
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Looks like a TS team member has just started working on a tool for this (maybe a side project). As of writing it doesn't appear to be finished but definitely worth watching.
https://github.com/sandersn/downlevel-dts

## Original answer

As far as I can find, nobody has written a tool to automatically generate these files yet. Most recent public word on this from a TypeScript team member is that [they don't intend to add this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31907#issuecomment-505267618) as a compiler feature. It was also [requested here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28797) with no response. So you may be stuck translating manually for now.

(Conceptually, a tool to do this would be a lot like "[Babel](https://babeljs.io) for typings": eliminating new syntax/keywords and "polyfilling" or eliminating new type helpers. It might even be possible to write as a Babel plugin.)